# Effective search in file which contains approximately 1 000 000 records?

Tags: python, search, indexing

I'm curious, how to search in (txt) file which contains approx. one million records. 
(I use Python)
What would be your first step? To load every record to array or another structure? I suppose this is too much uneffective according to memory (but I'm not an expert). Or should I make some kind of index over this file? What's your opinion?

Comment: Details, please. What are you searching for? How many things are you searching for? What's the data format? Do you get the entire job as one big batch, or do you need to handle queries as they come?

Comment: @user2357112 In my case, it is a bilingual dictionary in txt file. I want to search for one word translation everytime I use the dictionary. But it has to work as a web app too. So I think, it is uneffective to load whole document everytime I search for some word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to load the data into a database (such as `mysql`), index the appropriate columns and then use that to search the data.

While you could just load it all into memory in Python, that is by no means an optimal way of searching the data. Using indexes, that will take a lot of the heavy lifting away from you, and should provide pretty fast search times (so long as you have decent indexable columns)

If you are simply going to be looking up records based on a whole value from a single column (i.e. no wildcard searching or matching), then you could simply load the values into memory with Python. I use this method to load over 30 million transaction records into memory, and search based on a transaction ID. This was a better solution for me, because this large set of data is only used once in a rarely-run task, and I only need to reference the whole value of a single column.

Here's a quick example of how I achieve this.

```
transactions = {}
with open("transactions") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            lineSplit=line.split(",")
            transactions[lineSplit[0]] = lineSplit[1]
        except:
            pass
if "transid" in transactions:
    print transactions["transid"]
```